# Highcharts: getting blank chart with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, highcharts

I am trying to display Highcharts with JSON. First I try to get it working with a local JSON file. Later it'll get it's data from a django database.

My problem is: I am getting a blank page.

From this tutorial: 
[Highcharts.com Tutorial: PREPROCESS DATA USING JSON](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3). I made the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Besides that I created a file in the same directory, which contains the sample data given in the tutorial.

I don't know which of the scripts in the head are really necessary or which one I am missing. In the "your first chart" tutorial they only tell you to include the highcharts.js, even though you also need the jquery to get it working.

It actually worked like that (?) a couple days ago. I was really glad then, because I already did a lot of troubleshooting. Then I went further to get it working with JSON respone, resulting in blank pages. Now I can't figure which it isn't working again with local files.

There is also this tutorial: [Knowckstakc.com: different ways of loading highcharts data](http://www.knowstack.com/different-ways-of-loading-highcharts-data/). When I copy any of his solutions, all I see is also a blank spot where the chart is supposed to be.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: my data.json file:

```
[
[1,12],
[2,5],
[3,18],
[4,13],
[5,7],
[6,4],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[9,15],
[10,22]
]
```

Comment: Any javascript errors in the console or any requests on the network tab with status >= 400?

Comment: Could you add your data.json?

Comment: Looks like you have the highcharts.js included twice.  you should only include it once.

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` right before your `options.series[0].data = data`.  What appears in your console?

Comment: I added the content of my JSON file.
I just started the website in firefox to have better debugging with firebug and there it works.


In chrome it says: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/lunex/Schreibtisch/db/Charts/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Excited that it worked in firefox, I tried I now to use "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/" instead of the data.json. I got the following response:

Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Firefox: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Well it's not chrome, it's chromium.

Comment: You can't use the file protocol, you need to set up a web server, even for local dev.

Comment: Also, you need to include jquery before highcharts.js libraries.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a lot of people having this issue with different solutions. So I write this down and hope it'll help people in the future.

One problem I did was I spent too much time finding a working solution instead of troubleshoot the problem. To be honest, I didn't knew it better.

**Open the browser-console and read the error messages**

To solve these problems:

**Chromimium**:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 127.0.0.1:8000/users. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

**Firefox**:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 127.0.0.1:8000/users. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I did the following:

To avoid Crossiteskripting Conflicts install Django CORS Headers

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Add the corsheaders to my settings.py in my REST framework.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

...

MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

And allow all crossitescriptings. Which I wrote at the very end of the file.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```